# How to get Bootstrap 3 to push down page content on dropdown click

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Google AdSense prohibits websites from covering up ads with any element - even an expanded dropdown menu - so I am looking for a way to tell Bootstrap to push down the content of the page when a dropdown menu is clicked, so the leaderboard is pushed down instead of covered up.

I have looked on stackoverflow, and all of the questions I can find so far are asking how to overlay content and *not* push it down. I would like to do the inverse (I think this must have changed with Bootstrap 3).

I know this is possible, because on the responsive version of a site the toggle on the top right pushes down the page content, exactly I would like the dropdown menus to do:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

(open this link and shrink your browser window, then click the three lines in the top right).

How can I add that functionality to dropdown items when the menu is not collapsed?

Thank you!

---

EDIT:

Here is the jQuery I added to solve the solution based on @hsb1007's response:

```
$('.class-name-1').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
     $('.leaderboard').css('margin-top', 450);       
})
$('.class-name-2').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
     $('.leaderboard').css('margin-top', 200);       
})
$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
     $('.leaderboard').css('margin-top', 0);         
})
```

Comment: You can use 'shown.bs.dropdown'  which is triggered after it is shown.   From there you can grab the dropdown element, get the height. Although I haven't tried it, it should work in theory    haha theory doesn't mean anything though.   give it a shot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your site structure, it's hard to explain

From top of my head right now, you will have to put 'margin/padding' to your content bar to be pushed down.

Because other wise your menu will get wonky when dropdown menu appears.

Use their event based api. see below

```
$('#myDropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
     // this part will be trigged when dropdown is called

     // add margin / padding to your adsense container
})
```

To get the dynamic height,

```
$('#myDropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
     // this part will be trigged after dropdown is shown

     // Grab height of dropdown
     var height = $('.dropdown').outerHeight();
})
```

And again, I haven't actually tried any of the codes above, but it should work. =)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. I posted a quick follow up to the question, if you wouldn't mind answering it :)

Comment: height = $('.dropdown').outerHeight(); seems to return the height of the dropdown button, instead of the full navigation with items in it...

Comment: Without looking at the site, it is hard for me to give you exact code to paste in.  However, by the sound of it, you can do $('.nav').outerHeight()  + $('.dropdown').outerHeight()